# Git mergetool on Windows keeps being given filepath from Git install rather than repository root

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, mergetool, semantic-merge

I want to use SemanticMerge as my mergetool in Git, but when I try to perform a merge, I get a complaint from SemanticMerge saying that it cannot locate the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\my_repo_name\my_project\MyFile.cs.BASE.1234.cs` - which is absolutely correct as it should be at `C:\repositories\my_repo_name\my_project\MyFile.cs` and so on. For some reason although Git is working with the repositories in every other respect, it seems to be determined to pass the $BASE, $LOCAL and $REMOTE file paths with the Git install path prepended instead of the repository root.

I have been using the configuration suggested in [their own tutorial](http://rlbisbe.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/semantic-merge-as-the-default-merge-tool-with-git-on-windows/) as a starting point for this and the tool seems to work fine if given the correct paths, so I am guessing that somewhere between Git and MsysGit, there is some misconfiguration or miscommunication.

Comment: Can you try and repeat your merge *after* setting the environment variable `GIT_DIR` to `/path/to/your/repo/.git`? From a shell: `GIT_DIR=/path/to/your/repo/.git && git merge xxx`.

Comment: You should add your `.gitconfig` for SemanticMerge to your question, in case it's been misconfigured.

Comment: @Cupcake I thought of doing that but then it really is pretty much the same as the above link. I will try both of these next time I have a conflict come up.

Comment: @VonC if I set GIT_DIR to the path to my repo, git extensions fails altogether and thinks the repository is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if the SemanticMerge configuration is your issue, but if it is, you can try using these settings. I have it working on my work machine, but these are my personal machine settings, so they might not have been updated yet. These settings are for msysgit on Windows 7 by the way:

```
[mergetool "sm"]
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
    cmd = 'C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/PlasticSCM4/semanticmerge/semanticmergetool.exe' -b=\"$BASE\" -d=\"$LOCAL\" -s=\"$REMOTE\" -r=\"$MERGED\" -l=csharp -emt=\"mergetool.exe -b=\"\"@basefile\"\" -bn=\"\"@basesymbolic\"\" -s=\"\"@sourcefile\"\" -sn=\"\"@sourcesymbolic\"\" -d=\"\"@destinationfile\"\" -dn=\"\"@destinationsymbolic\"\" -r=\"\"@output\"\" -t=\"\"@filetype\"\" -i=\"\"@comparationmethod\"\" -e=\"\"@fileencoding\"\"\" -edt=\"mergetool.exe  -s=\"\"@sourcefile\"\" -sn=\"\"@sourcesymbolic\"\" -d=\"\"@destinationfile\"\" -dn=\"\"@destinationsymbolic\"\" -t=\"\"@filetype\"\" -i=\"\"@comparationmethod\"\" -e=\"\"@fileencoding\"\"\"
```

Comment: Adding this to the .git\config folder in my repo seems to have solved the problem to the extent that I can use it from the "merge" command line if not from GitExtensions.